# WMQ connection socket constantly closed between v9_client and v6_server

Tags: ibm-mq

We have a standalone java application using third-party tool to manage connection pooling, which worked for us in v6_client + v6_server setup for a long time.

Now we are trying to migrate from v6 to v9 (yes, we are pretty late to the party.....), and found v9_client connection to v6_server connection is constantly interrupted, meaning:

- Socket created by XAQueueConnectionFactory#createXAConnection() is always closed immediately, and the created XAConnection seems to be unaware of it.
- Due to socket close mentioned above, XASession created from the XAConnection.createXASession() always creates a new socket and close the socket after XASession.close().

We went throught the complete list of tunables for v9_client (XAQCF 
 column in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111800_.html) and only spot two potential new configs we haven't used in v6_client, *SHARECONVALLOWED* and *PROVIDERVERSION*. Unfortunately neither helps us out..... Specifically:

- We tried setShareConvAllowed(WMQConstants.WMQ_SHARE_CONV_ALLOWED_[YES/NO]) Considering there's no SHARECNV property in v6_server side, not a surprise.
- We tried "Migration/Restricted/Normal Mode" by setProviderVersion("[6/7/8") ([7/8] throws exceptions, as expected....).

Just wondering if anybody else had similar experience and could share some insights. We tried v9_server+v9_client and haven't seen any similar problem, so that could also be our eventual solution.....

Btw, the WMQ is hosted on linux (RedHat), and we only use products of MQXAQueueConnectionFactory on client side (ibm mq class for jms).

Thanks.

---

Additional details/updates.

---

[update-1]

--[playgrond setup]

v9_client jars:

```
javax.jms-api-2.0.jar
com.ibm.mq.allclient(-9.0.0.[1/5]).jar
```

v6_client jars:
  **in addition** to v9_client jars, introduced the following jars in eclipse classpath

```
com.ibm.dhbcore-1.0.jar 
com.ibm.mq.pcf-6.0.3.jar
com.ibm.mqjms-6.0.2.2.jar
com.ibm.mq-6.0.2.2.jar
com.ibm.mqetclient-6.0.2.2.jar
connector.jar
jta-1.1.jar
```

Testing code - single thread:

```
import javax.jms.*;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.*;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

public class MQSeries_simpleAuditQ {

    private static String queueManager = "QM.RCTQ.ALL.01";
    private static String host = "localhost";
    private static int port = 26005; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        MQXAQueueConnectionFactory queueFactory= new MQXAQueueConnectionFactory();

        System.out.println("\n\n\n*******************\nqueueFactory implementation version: " + 
                queueFactory.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion() + "*****************\n\n\n");

        queueFactory.setHostName(host);
        queueFactory.setPort(port);
        queueFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
        queueFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        if (queueFactory.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion().split("\\.")[0].equals("9")) {
            queueFactory.setProviderVersion("6");
            //queueFactory.setShareConvAllowed(WMQConstants.WMQ_SHARE_CONV_ALLOWED_YES);
    } 
        XASession xaSession;
        javax.jms.QueueConnection xaQueueConnection;
        try {
            // Obtain a QueueConnection
            System.out.println("Creating Connection...");
            xaQueueConnection = (QueueConnection)queueFactory.createXAConnection(" ", "");
            xaQueueConnection.start();

            for (int counter=0; counter<2; counter++) {
                try {
                    xaSession = ((XAConnection)xaQueueConnection).createXASession();
                    xaSession.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            } 
            System.out.println("Closing connection.... ");
            xaQueueConnection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error processing " + e.getMessage());
        } 

    }
}
```

--[observations]
v6_client only created and close a single socket, while v9_client (both 9.0.0.[1/5]):

- socket created and closed right after `xaQueueConnection = (QueueConnection)queueFactory.createXAConnection(" ", "");`
- in the inner for loop, socket created right after `xaSession = ((XAConnection)xaQueueConnection).createXASession();`, and closed after `xaSession.close();`

Naively i was expecting socket remains open until `xaQueueConnection.close()`.

---

[update-2]
Using `queueFactory.setProviderVersion("9");` and `queueFactory.setShareConvAllowed(WMQConstants.WMQ_SHARE_CONV_ALLOWED_YES);` for v9_server+v9_client, we don't see the same constant socket close issue in v6_server+v9_client, which is a good news.

---

[update-3] `MCAUSER` on attribute for all `SVRCONN` channel on v6_server. Same on v9_server (which doesn't have the same socket close problem when connected with the same v9_client).

```
display channel (SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN)
    MCAUSER(mqm) 

display channel (SYSTEM.AUTO.SVRCONN)
    MCAUSER( ) 

display channel (SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN)
    MCAUSER( )
```

---

[update-4]

I tried setting MCAUSER() to `mqm`, then using both  (blank) and `mqm` from client side, both can create connections, but still seeing the same unexpected socket close using v9_client+v6_user. After updating MCAUSER(), i always added `refresh security`, and restart the qmgr.

I also tried setting system variable to blank in eclipse before creating the connection using blank user, didn't help either.

---

[update-5]

Limiting our discussion to v9_client+v9_server. The async testing code below generates a ton of xasession create/close request, using limited number of existing connections. Using SHARECNV(1) we would also end up with unaffordable high TIME_WAIT count, but using larger than 1 SHARECNV (eg. 10) might introduce extra performance penalty......

Async testing code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

import javax.jms.*;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.*;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

public class MQSeries_simpleAuditQ_Async_v9 {

private static String queueManager = "QM.ALPQ.ALL.01";
private static int port = 26010; 

private static String host = "localhost";

private static int connCount = 20;
private static int amp = 100;
private static ExecutorService amplifier = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(amp);

public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
    MQXAQueueConnectionFactory queueFactory= new MQXAQueueConnectionFactory();

    System.out.println("\n\n\n*******************\nqueueFactory implementation version: " + 
            queueFactory.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion() + "*****************\n\n\n");

    queueFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    if (queueFactory.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion().split("\\.")[0].equals("9")) {
        queueFactory.setProviderVersion("9");
        queueFactory.setShareConvAllowed(WMQConstants.WMQ_SHARE_CONV_ALLOWED_YES);
    } 

    queueFactory.setHostName(host);
    queueFactory.setPort(port);
    queueFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
    //queueFactory.setChannel("");

    ArrayList<QueueConnection> xaQueueConnections = new ArrayList<QueueConnection>();
    try {
        // Obtain a QueueConnection
        System.out.println("Creating Connection...");
        //System.setProperty("user.name", "mqm");
        //System.out.println("system username: " + System.getProperty("user.name"));
        for (int ct=0; ct<connCount; ct++) {

            // xaQueueConnection instance of MQXAQueueConnection
            QueueConnection xaQueueConnection = (QueueConnection)queueFactory.createXAConnection(" ", "");
            xaQueueConnection.start();
            xaQueueConnections.add(xaQueueConnection);
        }

        ArrayList<Double> totalElapsedTimeRecord = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<FutureTask<Double>> taskBuffer = new ArrayList<FutureTask<Double>>();

        for (int loop=0; loop <= 10; loop++) {
            try {
                for (int i=0; i<amp; i++) {
                    int idx = (int)(Math.random()*((connCount)));
                    System.out.println("Using connection: " + idx);
                    FutureTask<Double> xaSessionPoker = new FutureTask<Double>(new XASessionPoker(xaQueueConnections.get(idx)));
                    amplifier.submit(xaSessionPoker);
                    taskBuffer.add(xaSessionPoker);                 
                }
                System.out.println("loop " + loop + " completed");

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        } 

        for (FutureTask<Double> xaSessionPoker : taskBuffer) {
            totalElapsedTimeRecord.add(xaSessionPoker.get());
        }
        System.out.println("Average xaSession poking time: " + calcAverage(totalElapsedTimeRecord));

        System.out.println("Closing connections.... ");
        for (QueueConnection xaQueueConnection : xaQueueConnections) {
            xaQueueConnection.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error processing " + e.getMessage());
    } 

    amplifier.shutdown();
}

private static double calcAverage(ArrayList<Double> myArr) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (Double val : myArr) {
        sum += val;
    }
    return sum/myArr.size();
}

// create and close session through QueueConnection object passed in.
private static class XASessionPoker implements Callable<Double> {

    // conn instance of MQXAQueueConnection. ref. QueueProviderService
    private QueueConnection conn;

    XASessionPoker(QueueConnection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }
    @Override
    public Double call() throws Exception {
        XASession xaSession;
        double elapsed = 0;
        try {
            final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // ref. DualSessionWrapper
            // xaSession instance of MQXAQueueSession
            xaSession = ((XAConnection) conn).createXASession();

            xaSession.close();
            final long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            elapsed = (end - start) / 1000.0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return elapsed;
    }  
}
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181387/discussion-on-question-by-fall14123-wmq-connection-socket-constantly-closed-betw).

Comment: As the beneficiary of this discussion, i really appreciate your enthusiasm, knowledge and help JoshMc, definitely boost my understanding of this mq product as a novice user. Meanwhile, i'll try to share the sample script i used on mq server side, just in case it helps to present a full picture of the problem we had. I understand v6 is a really old version and is no longer supported, so extra appreciation for your support! And please don't let it distract you too much from your daily job, as my intention is trying to get better understanding of the problem we had. our goal is to use v9 cli+svr.

Comment: Did setting the MCAUSER on the SVRCONN make it work with the v9 client to v6 server?  Also note that now that someone else is part of this discussion if you don't add @JoshMc to the comment it won't notify me of your response.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the queue manager's error log, the path is normally like `/var/mqm/qmgrs/<QMGRNAME>/errors/AMQERR01.LOG`, also look for any messages in a similar log `/var/mqm/errors/AMQERR01.LOG` as well as any FDC files produced under `/var/mqm/errors/*FDC`.  These may provide a clue to what the issue is.  Another option is to turn on a JMS trace on the client end and see if it shows you any details that may help.

Comment: hmmmm, nothing in `AMQERR0*.LOG`. Checked all the relevant directories i'm aware of, couldn't find any `*FDC*` file, trying to figure out how to generate it...

Comment: Also noticed something interesting uisng v9_client+v9_server, do you have recommendation/references on tunning `SHARECNV` on server side, assuming client-side `WMQ_SHARE_CONV_ALLOWED_YES`? we noticed somehow this `SHARECNV` seems to effect number of sockets created by xaSession from the same connection (expected), and we would naive think there must be some cost using sharedConversation... thanks again 

-----
going through your post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101651/websphere-mq-connection-tuning

Comment: our goals are (compare to v6_server+v6_client) : 1. control the number of sockets on server side; 2. avoid noticable performance degradation.

Comment: You can turn this on by starting your app with the these java system properties: `-Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status=ON` and `-Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.outputName=/path/to/put/mqjms.trc`.  If you don't specify the second it will default to `mqjavaclient_%PID%.trc` in the current directory.

Comment: v6 has a 1 to 1 relationship with a JMS session and MQ channel instance.  With v7.0.1.x and higher the share conversations play a role, `SHARECNV` is on the `SVRCONN` is the number of JMS sessions that are supported on a single channel instance.  Each channel instance would be a TCP socket from the JMS client to the queue manager.  There are other benefits such as bydirectional heartbeats that were also added at 7.0.1 and you need to have `SHARECNV(1)` minimum to still have those benefits, changing it to `SHARECNV(0)` force the channel to ask as a v6 channel.

Comment: having more that one conversation per channel can cause contention between sessions since all data flows over the same TCP socket, so if you have nay active sessions then setting the number down to 1 is probably best for performance reasons.   Am I to understand that you are not having a PROBLEM with v9 JMS client to v6 queue manager that you are only noticing a difference in TCP sockets being used?  It would be interesting test to set `SHARECNV(0)` and try your test from v9 JMS client to see if the behavior is the same, again not sure if this is a actual problem or just a behavior change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181973/discussion-between-fall14123-and-joshmc).

Comment: hi @JoshMc we seemingly got our in-house session pooling working in testing-env, and want to invite your inputs, in case we are doing something obviously wrong/stupid.... 

From a high level, we create an XAQueueSession pool for each XAQueueConnection, so that those pooled XAQueueSession objects can be re-used. An XAQueueSession object is returned to pool ONLY if current XATransaction is either committed or rolledback, otherwise the XAQueueSession object will be disposed and not returned to the pool after current XATransaction completes.

Comment: My questions are: 
1. Does it make sense to pool XASession objects? We were thinking about pooling `Session` (heavy weight), and then create `XASession` (light weight). However, either jms spec or ibm-mq api seems to support this option, and we implemented pooling on `XASession` instead of `Session`. I read both `CachingConnectionFactory` and `JmsPoolSession`, both of which use pooling on Session. I understand XASession is a subclass of Session, but just want to make sure i'm not making some fundamental mistakes....

Comment: `CachingConnectionFactory` https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/729ce4108de953d27e860394f04a0483a2d41e88/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.java#L436
`JmsPoolSession` https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms/blob/55cd4d331c9a8c0da5fdf474b15239753fa58bac/pooled-jms/src/main/java/org/messaginghub/pooled/jms/JmsPoolSession.java#L148

2. Is it safe to reuse `XASession` object, assuming we can gurantee the `XASession` object is returned to pool ONLY after the current XATransaction is either committed or rolledback? thanks

Comment: oh, two more things:
3. to keep V9 network usage (eg. connection count, connection performance, etc. ) relatively consistent with V6, what would be the recommended pick for `SHARECNV`? i vaguely remember reading the default `SHARECNV(10)` is probably the closest, but lost the link to that reference.....
4. is there any supported ibm implementation mitigating the removal of session pooling from the client jar, for standalone java applications? if i understand correctly, bitronix (the TM we use) doesn't provide session pooling, and i can imagine this would be a savior for people using both.

Comment: I'll admit that #1 and #2 are a outside of my knowledge base, but what you propose sounds very reasonable to me. #3, from a queue manager standpoint setting `SHARECNV(0)` makes the channel work in a v6 mode but is not recommended as it turns off other features besides shared conversations such as bi-directional heartbeats. `SHARECNV(1)` will give you one conversation/session per channel instance same as v6 but with benefit of bi-directional heartbeats.

Comment: `SHARECNV(1)` is recommended by IBM "Performance enhancements for distributed severs were then introduced in Version 8.0. To benefit from the new features that were introduced alongside shared conversations, without the performance impact on the distributed server, set SHARECNV to 1 on your Version 8.0 server connection channels." and "... for distributed servers, processing messages on channels that use the default configuration of 10 shared conversations is on average 15% slower than on channels that do not use shared conversations."

Comment: But on the client side there is no setting that emulates the connection pooling that v6 java classes contained. #4=no IBM implementation that I am aware of.  See my answer on this question for some more details on v6 and v7.0 and later "[IBM MQSeries connection pooling with Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53168185/ibm-mqseries-connection-pooling-with-tomcat/53233227#53233227)".  If you are able to share, I'm sure others would be helped by details of your XASession pooling solution, can this be detailed in a "self answer", I'd vote it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the root cause is a combination of `no more session pooling` + `bitronix TM doesn't offer session pooling across TX`. Specifically (in our case), bitronix manages `JmsPooledConnection` pooling, but everytime a (xa)session is used (under `JmsPooledConnection`), a new socket is created (`createXASession()`) and closed (`xaSession.close()`).

One solution, is to wrap the jms `connection` with `(xa)session` pool, similar to what's been done in https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms/tree/master/pooled-jms/src/main/java/org/messaginghub/pooled/jms

http://bjansen.github.io/java/2018/03/04/high-performance-mq-jms.html also suggests Spring `CachingConnectionFactory` works well, which sounds like a speical case of the first solution.