# IBM MQ Maximum Connections

Tags: spring, jboss, websphere, message-queue, mq

I am using IBM MQ in my application and the connection factory is defined at Jboss level. The maximum pool size property at Jboss level is configured as 50. The max instances per client configuration for the channel is set as 999999999. Sharing conversations stays as default 10.
I would appreciate if someone can elaborate more on how these connections work altogether?

I understand the maximum connections can be established by the JVM to Queue Manager is 50 (Max connection pool). If I have 50 message listener threads running in parallel all of them will be consumed. But the channel level, sharing conversation is 10 which means up to 10 conversations can be shared over a single TCP connection. In that case, we are not utilizing this capability as we exhausted the 50 connections. If 10 sharing allowed over a connection, we should see only 5 connections established for 50 messages?

Also if we have 100 messages to be consumed or loaded, as we have max channels set to a high value, does that mean 100 channels will be operated, or 10 channels with 10 sharing conversation each?

Please excuse me if the above assumptions are completely wrong as I am a very beginner to async architecture.

Comment: This provides the info.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101651/websphere-mq-connection-tuning/42106429#42106429

Comment: In the knowledge center there is a page that describes it. I can provide a link later. Connections = conversations. You get better performance with `SHRCONV(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing conversation is used to tune load balacing of mq server. When more than one sharing coversation is used, the client code acts as it has lock or round robin acces to channel instace. So if 50 listeners with sharing conversation of 10 are waiting for messages, then only 5 of them are active in any moment. One for each channel instance. No matter threading model in JVM.

By setting sharing conversations to 1 you are eliminating this contetion. The price is higher resource usage. [Keep this number to 1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q036143_.htm) unless you have large number of lightly used queues.